# Get the count of total rows and rows with value > 2 using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

How to calculate the size and count of rows with values > 2 for the below data frame:

```
df
     kpi_date    cell_name         call_drop
    2016-01-01    bgl_2345            0.2
    2016-01-01    bgl_2346            2.3
    2016-01-01    blg_2347            0.3
    2016-01-02    bgl_2345            1.4
    2016-01-02    bgl_2346            2.5
    2016-01-03    bgl_2347            2.7
```

and output should be

```
  kpi_date    call_drop   call_Drop>2
   2016-01-01    3             1
   2016-01-02    2             1
   2016-01-03    1             1
```

pls guide

Comment: You also should consider to attach your attempts for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Going step-by-step works:

```
grouped = df.groupby('kpi_date')
count = grouped['call_drop'].count()
greater2 = grouped.apply(lambda x: x['call_drop'][x['call_drop']> 2].count())
greater2.name = 'call_Drop>2'
print(pd.concat([count, greater2], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
            call_drop  call_Drop>2
kpi_date                          
2016-01-01          3            1
2016-01-02          2            1
2016-01-03          1            1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [Returning a Series to propagate names](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#returning-a-series-to-propagate-names), which leads the following code:

```
gd = df.groupby('kpi_date')
print(gd['call_drop'].apply(lambda x: {'call_drop':x.count(), 'call_drop>2':x[x>2].count()}).unstack())

Output:
          call_drop  call_drop>2
kpi_date                        
1/1/2016          3            1
2/1/2016          2            1
3/1/2016          1            1
```